# In ARKit how long and how accurately will a placed object remain in world space?

Tags: arkit

New to ARKit and trying to get clarification on how it remembers where things are.

A Terrible Use Case Example...but it conveys the thought...

I create a virtual post it note just about an inch to the left of it on the desk. Next day I come back and my reminder says to look at the note. I open the app and...because I saved the world space info, when I replace the object is it still an inch to the left of the iMac?

What if I have a post it at both my home and work desks?  I guess I’m confused with exactly how accurate is the positioning of items I put into ARKit space vs how GPS works in terms of remembering and determining position.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your note will stay there so long as the AR Session remains. However, if you were to close the app, there is no guarantee that the AR Session remains. Inside of Xcode, one of the function already suggests that the AR Session can be interrupted.

```
func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
}
```

It does not use GPS as the coordinates but rather the position inside the World Scene of your device. That is to say, the position of the note will be in the same position relative to the screen of your device regardless of your environment. It can be on your desk at home or it can be at some random position at your workplace, but the position on the screen should not change.

Comment: Sweet. So the hope would be that someday Apple will allow ARKit to “resume” the session and see if things are relatively where they were before. Great answer and thanks!

Comment: I guess that would be the best solution. Having said that ARKit still has a long of room for improvement. It was only realised mid of this year and I am definitely expecting more features to come.

Answer (score 3):

To extend upon the above answer, it's possible to have an AR node persist indefinitely now. There are tools collectively called ARCloud SDKs that let you create maps of physical spaces and attach AR nodes to specific accurate points in that map.

[Placenote SDK](https://placenote.com) is one such option.

Comment: interesting.  So this concept is conceivably possible now?  Have you heard or seen anything stating what happens if a person deletes the app or gets a new phone yet?  I'm assuming if it's cloud based it would just replicate those maps back to the user's device.

Comment: Yep! the maps would be managed external to the device so the app/ hardware isn't a concern!